# How to understand the difference between two command line options for cmake?

Tags: cmake

Describe difference between these two command lines:

```
C:\xxxxx> cmake -help

Usage

  $ cmake [options] <path-to-source>
  $ cmake [options] <path-to-existing-build>
```

Specify a source directory to (re-)generate a build system for it in the
current working directory.  Specify an existing build directory to
re-generate its build system.

The last description does not give me how to use the first, or the second.

Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Do you mind accepting one of the answers or is there still something to answer?

Answer (score 1):

This command:

```bash
cmake [options] <path>
```

works as follows:

- if *<path>* is not a valid (that is, already configured) CMake build directory, it is assumed to contain a `CMakeList.txt`. CMake will configure the **current working directory** as a build directory using `<path>/CMakeLists.txt` for source directory.
- if *<path>* is a valid CMake build directory, the command reconfigures that directory using the source directory assigned when you first configured that build directory

So the common usage patterns are:

- initial configuration:

  ```bash
  mkdir my-build-dir
  cd my-build-dir
  cmake [options] my-source-dir
  ```
- subsequent (re)configurations:

  ```bash
  cmake [options] my-build-dir # current-work-dir is not important
  ```
- alternative (initial) configuration using undocumented options:

  ```bash
  cmake -Hmy-source-dir -Bmy-build-dir [options] # cwd is not important
  ```

Answer (score 0):

When you use you do an in-tree build (`cmake .`), there is no difference.

When you do an out-of-tree build, there is a difference.

Suppose your project lives in `~/foo` and your current directory is `~/foo/build`

You have to run `cmake ..` for the first build. But for subsequent reconfigures, you can use `cmake .` because there is already a build there.